# Unable to submit rendered field

Tags: ajax, theming

I have a custom form with text field and a submit button.

```
$form['bid_amount'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t("Your Bid"),
  '#prefix' => '<div id="test-ajax">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);

$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Calculate your bid'),
  "#ajax" => array(
  'callback' => 'custom_callback',
  'wrapper' => 'test-ajax',
  'method' => 'replace',
  'effect' => 'fade',
  ),
);
}
```

What I want to do is, when 'bid_amount' is empty, and button is clicekd, 'bid_amount' should be rendered again with a prefilled value.
This is what I can do.
But at this time, when again button is clicked, with FILLED field of 'bid_amount', it shows up again with suggested value. Actuly it should be submitted this time.

Here is how I am rendering this ....

```
function custom_callback(&$form, &$form_state) {

    $next_bid = 100;
    return array(
      '#type' => 'ajax',
      '#commands' => array(
        ajax_command_replace("#test-ajax", render($form['bid_amount'] = array(
              '#type' => 'textfield',
              '#title' => t("Your Bid"),
              '#value' => $next_bid,
              '#prefix' => '<div id="test-ajax">',
              '#suffix' => '</div>',
        ))),
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: That code would cause a notice or an error: _Only variables should be passed by reference_.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.  I think the render function doesn't add "name" to the html so the form values are not submitted. I fixed this by adding them in the array

```
'#attributes' => array(
  'class' => array('edit-bid-amount'),
  'name' => 'bid_amount'
),
```

The function now is

```
function custom_callback(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $next_bid = 100;
  return array(
    '#type' => 'ajax',
    '#commands' => array(
      ajax_command_replace(
        "#test-ajax", render($form['bid_amount'] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => t("Your Bid"),
          '#value' => $next_bid,
          '#prefix' => '<div id="test-ajax">',
          '#attributes' => array(
            'class' => array('edit-bid-amount'),
            'name' => 'bid_amount'
          ),
          '#suffix' => '</div>',
          )
        )
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

Hth,
Sadashiv

Comment: This code has the same issue the code shown in the question has: It would cause a notice or an error: _Only variables should be passed by reference_.